# How to resize an image retrieved by file_get_contents and save it in a folder?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to retrieve image from a URL, resize it and save it to folder.

I have this code to retrieve image from url :

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/image/test.jpg';
$img = 'images/newtest.jpg';    
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

The problem is that before doing `file_put_contents`, I want to resize the image. How can I do it with php? Please Help me, I have searched on the internet but ended up with unclear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it if imagemagick is installed on your server...

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/image/test.jpg';
$img = 'images/newtest.jpg';    
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));    
$image = new Imagick( $img );
    $imageprops = $image->getImageGeometry();
    if ($imageprops['width'] <= 200 && $imageprops['height'] <= 200) {
        // don't upscale
    } else {
        $image->resizeImage(200,200, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GD2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to take a look at the [GD Image Processing Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)'s documentation, most specifically at the [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) function.

An example function doing the trick can look like this:

```
function resize_jpeg( $original_image, $new_height, $new_width, $filename )
{  
   // Resize the original image
   $image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
   $image_tmp = imagecreatefromjpeg ($original_image);
   imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image_tmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

   // Output
   imagejpeg($image_resized, $filename.".jpg", 100);
   imagedestroy($image_resized);
}
```

The function basically creates an image reference with the new height, loads the old one and then resamples it. Instead of `jpeg` you can use `png` and `gif` too. Be careful, as *GD* cannot properly resample animated GIF files.

`original_image` is a **file path** of the image to load. `new_width` and `new_height` are integers of the target width and height, respectively. `filename` is the target filename, without the `.jpg` extension in this example.